# Load an assembly from an embedded resource

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, resources

I would like to load a dll file (Test.dll) as an assembly. I am able to do this using both direct Visual Studio references (ie. loading the dll as a reference to my C# application) as well as loading the dll using the `Assembly.LoadFile(filename)` method. Now, I would like to add my dll file as an *embedded resource* to my Visual Studio application, and load the dll file as an assembly. I know how to load this resource as a byte array, is there some correlation between the byte array and the assembly that I could use? Furthermore, I need to be able to call a method located within the dll file. See the code below - it will further explain what I am doing.

```
Assembly SampleAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("WindowsFormsApplication2.ThisisaTESTDLL.dll");
Type myType = SampleAssembly.GetTypes()[0];
MethodInfo Method = myType.GetMethod("myVoid");
object myInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(myType,null);
Method.Invoke(myInstance,new object[] { "param1", "param1"});
```

If I am missing anything here, please respectfully let me know and I will edit the original post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(...)

That should get you a Stream object. You can read a byte array from that.

You can load that using Assembly.Load

Comment: I believe I stated in the question, I am already able to read in a byte array, is there some way to read the assembly from this byte array though?

Comment: this is where I sound ignorant .... I read the documentation for Assembly.Load and one of the "overloads" says "byte[]". Why, then, when I type "Assembly.Load" VS says "string" as the parameter? Is there some way to specify?

Comment: There are several overloads...Did you see arrows to cycle through the overloads list? You could also try using either resharper or the tools by devexpress. They improve intellisence quite a bit.

Comment: OHH! I never would have noticed that! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

I embedded AxInterop.WMPLib.dll and Interop.WMPLib.dll into my exe and got them loaded by using the following code. The code is placed just at the beginning of static void Main() in Program.cs file. Target framework is .NET 3.5 in my case. This code helped me bundle the dlls into the exe itself without having to deploy them through installers. I have hardcoded my names. In the code below "res" is the name of my resource "res.resx" that contains the two embedded dlls.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(    
(s, a) =>
{
    if (a.Name.Substring(0, a.Name.IndexOf(",")) == "AxInterop.WMPLib")
    {
        return Assembly.Load(res.AxInterop_WMPLib);
    }

    if (a.Name.Substring(0, a.Name.IndexOf(",")) == "Interop.WMPLib")
    {
        return Assembly.Load(res.Interop_WMPLib);
    }

    return null;
});
```